How to Construct a Larger Set of Generators for Sp(2n, q) to Optimize Diameter?
For the symplectic group Sp(2n, q) over a finite field of order q, I am interested in constructing a set of generators that produces a Cayley graph with a "good diameter." Specifically:
By "good diameter," I mean that the diameter of the Cayley graph (with respect to this generating set) is as small as possible relative to the size of the group. I understand that Sp(2n, q) can be generated by just two elements, however I have done some numerical tests with GAP and found that e.g for Sp(14,2) it can require words very large lenghts when using the minimal generating set. (For a random element of Sp(14,2) generated by the default seed on its first use in GAP, we get a word length of 1,085,467)
My focus is not on minimizing the number of generators but rather on finding a (possibly much larger) set of generators that leads to better expansion properties or diameter bounds in the Cayley graph. I’m happy to work with a large generating set if that helps optimize the graph properties.
My main question:
Constructing Generators: What are the best-known methods for constructing explicit generating sets for Sp(2n, q) that result in a Cayley graph with good diameter? Are there any general principles for selecting generators in this context?

Here's a MathJax tutorial :)

Hi, what should I edit?

The group names and the numbers need to be MathJax.  Also, some context would help.  What have you tried? What are you studying? What text is this drawn from, if any? If not, how did the question arise? What kind of approaches (to similar problems) are you familiar with? What kind of answer are you looking for? Basic approach, hint, explanation, something else? Is this question something you think you should be able to answer? Why or why not?
